# React Syntax Adding variables to URL get call

Tags: reactjs, get

I have a component which is performing a function Get call via a URL which needs to have two variables in the URL string. Via console.log I know that the variables are being correctly pulled into the function. If I hard code the variables into the URL the call is working (I tested in the browser) but if I insert them via variable the get call doesn't work. Here is how the function is set up

```
loadTableData({getId: newId, getResourceId: newResource}) {
    console.log('this is the passed Id and resource ID for loadTableData', newId + " " + newResource)
    return axios.get(`https://10.16.147.159/bpocore/market/api/v1/resources/${newResource}/operations/${newId}`)
}
```

If I physically copy/paste newResource and newId variables above into the axios.get URL, it works perfectly. However if I leave it as shown above I get incorrect output. Is there a problem with the syntax? I hope my code is sufficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting error. I am getting two different versions of the JSON on the callback. The correct JSON is the one that I receive when I copy/paste the variable values directly into the URL.